# Where is the rvalue coming from?

Tags: c++, return-value, rvalue, lvalue-to-rvalue

I learning about references and value categories because the latter are mentioned in some C++ errors.

I have a function, `referenceToDouble` that takes in references to double. From watching [this video on value categories](https://youtu.be/wkWtRDrjEH4), I believe that `left` and `right` below are **lvalue references to double**.

In `main` when I make variables `a` and `b` of type `double`, I don't get an error. Code below shows `a` and `b` of type `float` which gives me an error.

```cpp
#include <cassert>

double referenceToDouble(double& left, double& right) {
    if (left >= right) {
        right = left;
    }
    else {
        left = right;
    }

    return left;
}

int main() {
    float a = 55.5;
    float b = 55.5;

    assert(55.5 == referenceToDouble(a, b));
}
```

When I switch the data type of `a` and `b` to `float`, I get this error.

```
checkReferences.cpp: In function 'int main()':
checkReferences.cpp:18:35: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'double&' to an rvalue of type 'double'
   18 |  assert(55.5 == referenceToDouble(a, b));
      |                                   ^
checkReferences.cpp:3:34: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'double referenceToDouble(double&, double&)'
    3 | double referenceToDouble(double& left, double& right) {
      |                          ~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

My questions are:

- where is the rvalue coming from?
- Is there a temporary variable that contains the `double` value of `a`
  that was cast from `float`? And is this temporary then the `rvalue`?
- Or is the error referring to the `55.5` which is a literal and
  therefore an rvalue?
- Is the return type not involved here? I think it isn't because this
  is a return by value and not by reference.

I tried [reading the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032945/error-cannot-bind-non-const-lvalue-reference-of-type-int-to-an-rvalue-of-typ#answer-54032989) that had a similar error but I wasn't able to dispel my doubts. I also think I know what the solution (use `double`) is but I am trying to understanding what is going on under the hood.

Comment: I think this boils down to a question about how your particular compiler warnings are worded and how your compiler works, because when I try Clang 13.0.0 or GCC 11.2 on https://godbolt.org, there is no mention of a `double` rvalue.  What particular compiler are you using?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Are you sure? https://godbolt.org/z/T9zYrvo17

Comment: Indeed, when I click on your link it says "value of type 'float'" and does not say "rvalue of type 'double'".

Comment: I am using `g++` more specifically `g++ (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a temporary variable that contains the double value of a that was cast from float? And is this temporary then the rvalue?

Yes. `left` and `right` with type `double&` can't bind to `float`s directly. They have to be converted to `double`s firstly, which are temporaries (rvalues) and can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const.

If you change the type of `left` and `right` to `const double&` then it'll work fine. The converted `double` temporaries (rvalues) could be bound to lvalue-reference to `const`.