# Why the overloaded+ operator cannot be used with a primitive type static_cast to a class?

Tags: c++, casting, operators

I'm just starting to dive into the depths of C++. Recently I came across a task to create a bMoney class that will store some monetary value. At the same time, the class must have overloaded operators +, -, * and /. Also, this class must have a constructor that can be used when casting types.

Here's my code with all operators prototypes.

```cpp
сlass bMoney {
  private:
    long double money;
    
  public:
    explicit bMoney(long double _money = 0.0L) noexcept : money(_money) {};

    bMoney operator+(bMoney &other) const;
    bMoney operator-(bMoney &other) const;
    bMoney operator*(long double times) const;
    bMoney operator/(long double times) const;
};
```

However, in the process of testing the code, I encountered an interesting error. Here is my code:

```cpp
bMoney bm1(1.0);
long double ld = 2.0
bMoney bm2 = bm1 + static_cast<bMoney>(ld); //here's the error
```

I am warned that there is no + operator corresponding to such operators (bMoney + bMoney). However, this warning disappeared as soon as I removed the argument reference in the + operator. Why is this happening? I think it has something to do with static_cast, but still can't figure it out. If you can, please help me

I tried doing static_cast<bMoney>(&ld), but it didn't help. I'm just starting to understand pointers and references, so I'm a little afraid of them.

Comment: `bMoney operator+(bMoney &other) const;` is the wrong signature for `operator+`. `a + b` should neither modify `a` nor `b`

Comment: please include the warning/error message in the question

Comment: `static_cast<bMoney>(ld)` is an rvalue. You can't bind rvalue to non-`const` lvalue reference.

Comment: What the comments are, for some reason, not mentioning is that to fix it, just add `const`: `bMoney operator+(const bMoney &other) const;`

Comment: @PeteBecker: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @ScottHunter -- it's a sketch of an answer; maybe someone will fill in the details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032945/error-cannot-bind-non-const-lvalue-reference-of-type-int-to-an-rvalue-of-typ

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you so much! It's working now. I am a little familiar with the concepts of rvalue and lvalue. I need to pay more attention to them. Thanks again!

Comment: @George: Don't thank me; I just commented on another comment that had actual helpful information.

Comment: The cast is not the culprit - this will happen with any temporary object, for instance `bm1 + bMoney(ld)` (which is the more idiomatic way of writing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static_cast` creates a **prvalue**(a temporary object) while your `operator+` expects a `mutable` **lvalue** - due to `bMoney&` argument. **prvalue**s cannot bind to `mutable` **lvalue** references. When you remove the reference specifier the prvalue is directly initialized into the argument via **copy-elision**.
On the other hand, **`const` lvalue references** are able to bind to **rvalue**s. So the usual practice of declaring operator arguments as **`const` lvalue references** can eliminate the problem.

By the way, this is not called *diving into C++*. This is basic modern C++ material; but those dinosaur instructors in formal academia are are too ignorant to teach you the right stuff. Get yourself a book titled "Modern C++" and published well after 2011. What is perceived as basic/advanced by the average developer is often the opposite of reality. The most basic things in modern C++ are the most recent ones, while most of the stuff before C++11 is advanced. Raw pointers are expert, smart pointers are intermediate, but STL containers and ranges are beginner level.